# How to fix the border radius?

Tags: html, css, border, border-radius

The border radius is not working when I include the gradient border color. How can I fix this?

```
border: 2px solid transparent;
border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #56B6DF 0%, #9063C4 100%);
border-image-slice: 1;
border-radius: 3px;
```